# NPE at custom dialog box

Tags: java, android

I created an activity with two buttons in which a custom dialog box will be shown depending on the type of button clicked

I have created an xml file for the dialog box

dialog.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lv_dialog"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="# Do you know?"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textSize="25px"
         android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THE FACT IS DISPLAYED HERE"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textSize="30px"
         android:layout_marginTop="10px"
         android:id="@+id/txtfact"
                />

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THE ANSWER STATUS IS DISPLAYED HERE"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textSize="32px"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:layout_marginTop="10px"
         android:id="@+id/txtanswer"
                />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="THE SCORE IS DISPLAYED HERE"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:textSize="32px"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:layout_marginTop="10px"
         android:id="@+id/txtscore"
                />
    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="GOTO NEXT QUESTION"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
       android:layout_marginTop="20px"
       android:id="@+id/btngotonext"
       />

     </LinearLayout>
```

THe activity main is

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CORRECT CHOICE"
        android:id="@+id/btncorrect"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WRONG CHOICE"
        android:id="@+id/btnwrong"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The main class is :

```
package com.example.custom_fifa_dialog;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Button btncorrect,btnwrong,btngotonext;
        LinearLayout lv_dialog;
        Dialog dialog;
        databasemanager dbm;
        String s="";
        TextView txtfact,txtanswer,txtscore;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            dbm=new databasemanager(this);
            dialog=new Dialog(this);

            btncorrect=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btncorrect);
            btnwrong=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnwrong);
            lv_dialog=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv_dialog);

            btncorrect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    lv_dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                    txtfact=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtfact);
                    txtanswer=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtanswer);
                    txtscore=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtscore);
                    btngotonext=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btngotonext);
                    int random=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((736 -1) + 1));
                    dialog.setTitle("RESULT");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+random,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     s=dbm.getdouknow(random);
                    txtfact.setText(s);
                    txtanswer.setText("CORRECT ANSWER");
                    txtscore.setText("SCORE:25");
                    btngotonext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                       dialog.show();


                }
            });
            btnwrong.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    lv_dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                    txtfact=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtfact);
                    txtanswer=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtanswer);
                    txtscore=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtscore);
                    btngotonext=(Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btngotonext);
                    int random=1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((736 -1) + 1));
                    dialog.setTitle("RESULT");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+random,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     s=dbm.getdouknow(random);
                    txtfact.setText(s);
                    txtanswer.setText("WRONG ANSWER");
                    txtscore.setText("SCORE:0");
                    btngotonext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                      dialog.show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I am getting a NPE at the line where the background color is set:

LOGCAT:

```
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253): Process: com.example.custom_fifa_dialog, PID: 18253
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at com.example.custom_fifa_dialog.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-09 10:45:00.660: E/AndroidRuntime(18253):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help!

Comment: what is lv_dailog do you mean to load this dialog.xml into lv_dailog?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `lv_dialog=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv_dialog);`, you are calling `findViewById()` on *the current Activity*, not the dialog. Since the LinearLayout with id `lv_dialog` is in the Dialog's layout and not the Activity, this will return null.

Your dialog's layout doesn't even get inflated until you call `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);`.

One way to fix this would be to not retrieve the LinearLayout until after you set the Dialog's layout, like so:

```
btncorrect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
        lv_dialog=(LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv_dialog);
        lv_dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: STILL GETTING THE NPE AT THE LINE 
lv_dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));

Comment: Sorry about that, had a typo in my answer. You need to call `dialog.findViewById()`, not `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this line after you setContent for dialog. At the beginning, you get the null reference.

```
lv_dialog=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv_dialog);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity `lv_dialog` is part of `dialog.xml` file not part of `activity_main`.
So
make instance of `lv_dialog` after setting dialog layout as
Change this

```
lv_dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
```

to

```
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
lv_dialog=(LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.lv_dialog);
 lv_dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
```

and remove

```
lv_dialog=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lv_dialog);
```

from `OnCreate` function